# Data Layer is not pushed to Google Analytics from GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I have trouble with [GTM](https://tagmanager.google.com/) pushing data to [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/).

I have the next data in `dataLayer`:

http://icecream.me/2962ff66f02fe5260a1f6f10103d6bf5

I created variables in GTM for each param and tag *'data layer'* which is called by page view:

http://icecream.me/e96344ae08ca6f5abe5436852dc61a67

I see that tag is called in GTM:

http://icecream.me/ca14533050bdbd56e94695257a459b29

I set dimensions in GA:

http://icecream.me/f365dc263bcaa1a7e0c64da96e7afe14

But I can't see data in GA. Nor in users:

http://icecream.me/e7cbe35a38e0dc520428dc120e41e94e

Can I also set up some event to see the data for online users? 
Thanks.

Comment: Everything is ok, I saw, that we have several GA Universal tags, in debugger data came from all of them, but seems that in GUI displayed the first one where metrics where not pushed. With metrics params everything is ok in my sample.

Answer (score 1):

In your data-layer tag I see data is coming as metric and you have created dimensions.
See following image for example, my tag is showing data as dimensions. I think this is the issue.

[image: My Example Tag]

In your tag, please make sure you are setting custom dimensions.